collapse_rows removes topmost entry
When using kableExtra::collapse_rows with valign="top", the function seems to remove the top entry (see reprex below, the Species entry for "Setosa" is missing). When I open the corresponding tex document, I see that the entry for "Setosa" is there, but has the following on line 238 of the .tex document: \multirow[t]{-50}{*}{\raggedright\arraybackslash setosa}. I assume the {-50} is pushing it to somewhere outside the table bounds.
Does anyone have a good workaround solution for keeping the values in the collapse rows at the top, but not having kableExtra remove them?
---
title: "PDF kable and collapse_rows"
output: 
  pdf_document:
      keep_tex: true
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
knitr::kable(iris) |>
  kableExtra::collapse_rows(5, valign = "top", row_group_label_position = "identity")
```


You're actually losing a lot of rows and your labels moved to the middle. You're missing an argument you need - to the call for collapse_rows() you need to add longtable_clean_cut = F because your groups extend beyond one page (explained in the package). If you look at the tex file before this change it actually shows 'no pagebreak' in between groups, which means anything beyond a page goes to the land of lost information.

Could use output: html_document and print as PDF from a web browser as a work around to keep a PDF output document. When I did this I was able to retain the species column and not have it cut off like it did for latex.

This is probably a duplicate question, but I haven't looked.
Never use knitr::kable() with kableExtra.  Always use kableExtra::kbl() in its place.
When you do that, it works.

Thank you. This does indeed work. For posterity and those looking at this in the future....this answer does introduce new problems. The default cuts off the table after one page, and adding longtable = TRUE to the kbl() function re-introduces the original problems (except that all values in the collapsed rows simply disappear). In my experience, kable/kableExtra is phenomenal with html outputs, but perhaps not quite at the level of PDF big leagues.

@code_cowboy that sounds like a bug.  You should put together a reprex and report it on the kableextra issues page.  (I am unable to do that myself for a couple of weeks and won't remember the context by then.)
